# Implementing C++/clr's auto_handle functionality in C#

Tags: c#, .net, il, raii

I have been looking for a way to ensure that member variables of a class are cleaned up in all cases such as an exception at the end of the classes constructor.

Because they are member variables, the "try, catch" and "using" patterns are not useful.
I have noticed that .NET C++ (C++ /clr:safe) provides an emulation of smart pointers (Called msclr::auto_handle) such as auto_ptr or shared_ptr. This is extremely useful because I can have deterministic destruction of limited resources such as threads or sockets in a very clean way.

I have been analysing the IL produced with C++ /clr and noticed that all it actually seems to do is spam the IL with try/faults in every single function that modifies the encapsulated data.

I have included the IL listing for anyone interested. (The try/fault were not added by me and were added by the C++/clr compiler)

```
  MyClass()
  {
        myDisposable.reset(gcnew MyDisposable());
        throw gcnew Exception("Hello World");
        // myDisposable needs to clean up now
        // because it is very large or locks a limited resource.
        // Luckily with RAII.. it does!
  }
```

... becomes...

```
  .try
  {
  IL_0006:  ldarg.0
  IL_0007:  ldloc.0
  IL_0008:  stfld      class msclr.'auto_handle<MyDisposable>' modreq([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsByValue) MyClass::myDisposable
  IL_000d:  ldarg.0
  IL_000e:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
  IL_0013:  ldarg.0
  IL_0014:  ldfld      class msclr.'auto_handle<MyDisposable>' modreq([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsByValue) MyClass::myDisposable
  IL_0019:  newobj     instance void MyDisposable::.ctor()
  IL_001e:  call       instance void msclr.'auto_handle<MyDisposable>'::reset(class MyDisposable)
  IL_0023:  ldstr      "Hello World"
  IL_0028:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.Exception::.ctor(string)
  IL_002d:  throw
  IL_002e:  leave.s    IL_003c
  }  // end .try
  fault
  {
  IL_0030:  ldarg.0
  IL_0031:  ldfld      class msclr.'auto_handle<MyDisposable>' modreq([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsByValue) MyClass::myDisposable
  IL_0036:  callvirt   instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
  IL_003b:  endfinally
  }  // end handler
```

Is there a similar way achieve this with C# since my software is going to be very complex and it will be extremely dangerous and bug prone for me to handle all this myself.
So does anyone know of a technique or even a post build step which can add this additional IL code in automatically so I can emulate RAII with C#?

Edit: (Another example)

```
  ref class MyClass
  {
  private:
        msclr::auto_handle<MyDisposable> myDisposable;

  public:
        MyClass()
        {
              myDisposable.reset(gcnew MyDisposable());
              throw gcnew Exception("Hello World");
              // myDisposable needs to clean up now because it is very large or locks a limited resource.
        }
  };
```

myDisposable is a member variable. When "Hello World" is thrown from the constructor, myDisposable actually gets disposed immediately. Can I get the same functionality in C#?
We have confirmed that using cannot work because it is on a member variable and a try/catch in every function is a very poor solution.

Best Regards,

Karsten

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to emulate RAII in C#? I think that in most cases, constructors shouldn't throw exceptions that would cause undisposed resources. And in the cases where that does happen, the nondeterministic cleanup using finalizers should be enough.

Comment: Constructors need to be able to throw exceptions.
RAII prevents undisposed resources.
I need to be able to perform cleanup tasks such as closing a socket or terminating a thread. Nondeterministic is not acceptible for this. C++'s RAII is there for this reason and I want to duplicate it in C# without having messy convoluted code.

Comment: Wrapping the body of the c'tor in `try/catch` would be my recommendation.  If an error occurs clean up in the `catch`.  If you want to pass the exception along, `throw` at the end.  That should give you something very similar to that il

Comment: Hmm, that seems to be the only choice. In which case I will probably stick to C++/CLR since it seems more elegant in this scenario since you don't need to deal with the memory management manually :/

Answer (score 5):

The auto_handle<> template class in C++/CLI uses a feature that's specific to the C++/CLI compiler called "stack semantics".  A feature that's very familiar to C++ programmers and the core runtime support behind RAII.  Simply put, the compiler ensures that the destructor is called at the end of the scope block.  You see the .try/fault blocks emitted in the IL to ensure that the destructor is called even when the code throws an exception.

The destructor of the auto_handle class calls the destructor of the object it wraps.  That's where the similarity with C++ ends, the destructor of a C++/CLI class is the IDisposable.Dispose() method.  The "real" destructor is the finalizer of the class, denoted by the `!classname` syntax.

And the similarity with C# starts, it is the *exact* equivalent of the **using** statement.  It too ensures that the Dispose() method is called and also uses try/finally to ensures that happens even when there are exceptions.  Instead of adding a *using* keyword to C++/CLI, the designers simply chose to select syntax that's more familiar to C++ programmers.  Also seen in the usage of IDisposable, you cannot call Dispose() but must use the *delete* operator to call it.

So if you like auto_handle<> in C++/CLI then you'll have the exact same reasons to like *using* in C#.

Do beware of the great difference between RAII in C++ vs auto_handle/using in managed code.  You often need RAII to release memory in C++, that's completely unnecessary in a managed language.  Nor can you, it's the job of the garbage collector.  You only *ought to* use *using* when you create an object that inherits IDisposable.  Certainly not every class in .NET does.  It is also optional, not required, the finalizer of a class always ensures that unmanaged resources are released when it wasn't done early with Dispose().

In exceptional cases, due to gritty exception handling or just too much pain in tracking life-time of an object it is certainly okay to skip a Dispose() call.  A standard example of such a class in the .NET framework is the Thread class.  It has 5 disposable native resources but doesn't implement IDisposable.  Because writing the code to ensure it is called tends to defeat the point of using threads.

Comment: Be careful about saying that the finalizer "always" releases some resource.  People tend to confuse C# finalizer as having the same cleanup contract/semantics as a C++ destructor. `Thread` is only guaranteed by the CLR to be finalized because it is a `CriticalFinalizerObject`.

Comment: how can it be the exact equivalent of the using statement when the using statement can only be used within a single function?
As the snippet above shows, myDisposable is a reference to a member variable. For example if it was a thread that I wanted to live for the lifetime of my class.

Comment: I missed that.  But that's a nasty trap with auto_handle, it will *not* do anything when you use it on a field.  Only when you take advantage of stack semantics can it do what it promises and that requires declaring it inside a method body.  Making C++/CLI look like C++ was, frankly, a design mistake that gets too many C++ programmers in trouble.  Only the syntax is similar, runtime behavior certainly is not.  Not a lot of lols when they find out.

Comment: But in the example above I had used it on a member variable (myDisposable). And it seems to add the try/catches for me in every function it is used, allowing me to pretend that RAII is happening. The IL is ugly as ever, but the code itself seems acceptable. (much nicer than the c# equivalent)

Comment: I don't know what that code looks like, smells like you are using its copy constructor.  Given that you `.` instead of `->`.  This is getting a bit irrelevant, unless you actually favor writing C++/CLI code instead of C# code.  Which is entirely possible of course, the CLR doesn't care.

Comment: ? Not entirely sure what you mean.
With almost all smart pointers, they go on the stack (they are local automatic variables) thus you access them with '.'
However, to access and dereference their contained pointer, you use '->'.
I favour neither language but I would ideally like to find a solution to my question. It seems that .NET languages completely overlooks this critical issue but C++.NET actually provides a viiable workaround that I really would like to use in C# (due to the abilities of other developers at work). I am going to add another example to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use member variables in a using:

```
class junk
{
    private IDisposable somevar;
    void SomeFunc()
    {
        using (somevar = SomeOtherFunc())
        {
           YesAnotherFunc();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: after SomeFunc has completed, would somevar become disposed? That would be useless. Variables that have their value set in the constructor and are destroyed when the class is no longer needed. How would I do that with using?

Comment: If you want the variable disposed when the class is disposed, then implement IDisposable at the class level. That's a standard pattern. Am I missing something?

Comment: The issue with that pattern is that it doesn't actually work as required. For example, if an exception is thrown at the end of my class constructor the resources (IDisposable classes) that have been constructed just before the exception have no way of being cleaned up unless explicitly being wrapped in a try catch (Which is what C++/clr actually does behind the scenes). This is not done in C# unless written in a manual and extremely messy way.